# ограничение на количество в 128 адресов squid 3.4.8

Tags: proxy, squid, ipv6

Я использую squid 3.4.8 для поднятия ipv6 прокси, хотел поднять много прокси, но натолкнулся на следующее ограничение в логах:

```
WARNING: You have too many 'http_port' lines
The limit is 128
```

Как можно увеличить это количество? Видел, что можно прописать

```
#define MAXHTTPPORTS                    128
```

в squid/src/defines.h, но у меня нет такого файла. Куда это нужно прописать и достаточно ли будет этого для увеличения количества адресов?

Ос - debian 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так этот файл - часть исходников SQUID. Это вам надо скачать все исходники, среду сборки, все связанные библиотеки и пересобрать SQUID.